# Safari input file styling with CSS?

Tags: css, file, input, safari

How does one style a form input field of type `file` for Safari, Chrome, and other WebKit-based browsers?

Right now, all I get is the <kbd>Choose File</kbd> button displayed on top of the usual text input box.

I've looked around a bit on Google, but haven't really seen anything helpful.

Comment: I've actually found what works.

I had another legacy css rule interact with my new form that triggered a box to be displayed around the input. 

Thanks for your quick answers though, it pointed me in the right direction.

Cheers!

Comment: Could you post what your legacy css rule that broke the style was so that others could avoid it?

Answer (score 4):

*All rendering engines automatically generate a button when an  is created. Historically, that button has been completely un-styleable. However, recently Trident and WebKit have added hooks through pseudo-elements.*

**Trident**

As of IE10 the file input button can be styled using the `::-ms-browse` pseudo-element. Basically any CSS rules that you apply a regular button can be applied to the pseudo-element. For example:

```
<input type="file">

::-ms-browse {
    background: black;
    color: red;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

This displays as follows in IE10 on Windows 8:

[image]

**WebKit**

WebKit provides a hook for its file input button with the `::-webkit-file-upload-button` pseudo-element. Again pretty much any CSS rule can be applied, therefore the Trident example will work here as well:

```
<input type="file">

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    background: black;
    color: red;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

This displays as follows in Chrome 26 on OS X:

[image]

Comment: source: http://tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/

Answer (score 1):

Few days ago I had task to stylize an `input="file"` with CSS (mostly CSS3 with extra effects) and it is possible to do that.

I've written (or made small rewrites to filestyle plugin) a jQuery plugin. Its core behaviour is the same with images but I've totally replaced images with `span`s and `div`s. The plugin hides `input="file"` then builds a wrapper with CSS and finally triggers click actions on hidden input.

I hope it will be helpful for everyone.

[**Here's an example of how to style `input="file"` with only CSS.**](http://rpiesnikowski.blogspot.com/2012/04/styling-input-file-only-with-css-no.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can. Apple only recently decided to enable styling of their form controls. They believe that it's harder to find buttons and inputs when they don't look like buttons an inputs - so they might not let you style their file upload inputs yet.

I'm around 90% sure you can't do it.

Comment: Actually, i don't mind the Apple button itself. I just want to prevent the box from appearing underneath the button.

Answer (score 0):

Having a Flash uploader can give even more pain:

It is only working in IE in the same session as your browser and in all other browers it makes a new session, so you will kicked out of your back end secure app.

The only solution to that is sending your session data to the Flash as well... there you go!

I landed on this page looking or ways to style the file input item for Safari... I have lots of them in a table cell of only 150px wide but these inputs are forcing it bigger.

I have found just one solution until now, and that is to let them float above the rest using `style="position:absolute;z-index:2"` while my TD has `position:relative` styling.

It's a bad bad solution, I know!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 4 will let you style input elements (in a round about way): [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications#Using_hidden_file_input_elements_using_the_click%28%29_method)

Hopefully the other browsers will catch on to what an enormous pain point this removes.

Answer (score 0):

If your only interested in webkit browsers, you can use their built in pseudo selectors to target different parts of the file input element. `input::-webkit-file-upload-button {...}`, for example.